# Сколько памяти займёт типизированный указатель на массив из 100 4-ёхбайтовых элементов?

Tags: delphi, указатели

```
type
arr  = array [0..100] of integer;
PArr = ^arr;
var 
a : array [0..10] of integer;
pa: parr;
begin
...
pa:=@a;
```

---

Вопрос: сколько памяти займёт pa?; a?; всего?
Не решит ли компилятор, что если pa указывает на массив из 100 элементов, то программе нужно отделить все 100*4 байт памяти? И как  это можно проверить с  помощью стандартного debug'ера Embarcadero Delphi XE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неуверен что правильно помню но помоему указатель всегда занимает 1 регистр
те для 32 битной платформы это 4 байта для 64 битной 8.

те pa -4 байта

a  -11*4(integer) байта

Да а в вашем случае проблема может возникнуть при обрашении скажем к 11 элементу массива через "pa" т.к. ошибки не возникнет а просто считается из памяти то что там есть.

Comment: Но почему тогда  sizeof(pa^) возвращает не 11*4 байта, 101*4 байта?!

Comment: @ололо, потому что тип pa - указатель на массив из 101 элементов. Если объявить pa просто как pointer, то скорее всего sizeof(pa^) будет равно 1.